# Debezium: Stream messages in one topic

Tags: postgresql, debezium, debezium-engine

I'm fairly new to Debezium and I understand that Debezium generates a topic for a specific table and that if there is an update/ delete on that table, it will send a message to Kafka via that topic.

I was wondering if you could have 1 topic that listens to multiple tables (i.e. have 1 consumer on the application side)? - the concern I have here is that if there are multiple topics the application subscribes to, that means lots of threads.